# Loop to split a String inside Array Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

How do I have the follow output ["1", "2", "3", "4", ...] or ["one", "two", "three", "four", ...] from this Array ["1 one", "2 two", "3 three", "4 four", ...].

Comment: A loop is not needed. Call `map` and split the string in the closure by `space` and return the first or second item.

Comment: Thanks vadian, but how can I call map to split a String inside an array?

Comment: `let input = ["1 one", "2 two", "3 three", "4 four"]
var out1:[String] = []
var out2:[String] = []
input.forEach{
    guard case let comps = $0.components(separatedBy: " "), let first = comps.first, let last = comps.last else { return }
    out1.append(first)
    out2.append(last)
}`

Comment: It is works, thanks Leo Dabus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split it with a for loop.

```
var str = ["1 one", "2 two", "3 three", "4 four"]

var first: [String] = []
var second: [String] = []
var splited: [String] = []

for value in str {
    splited = value.components(separatedBy: " ")
    first.append(splited[0])
    second.append(splited[1])
}
```

thanks to @Martin R

Comment: @MartinR, there are different ways in using for loop. with different pros and cons. at first i used `for i in 0...str.count - 1 {...}`. but after that i changed my mind.

Comment: @MartinR what is your suggestion?
the best way of that

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following solution on this format `Array ["1 one", "2 two", "3 three", "4 four", ...]`

```
var firstValArr : [String]?
var lastValArr : [String]?
for i in 0 ..< yourArray.count {
    let arrayElement = yourArray[i]
    let splitArrayElement = arrayElement.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let firstValue    = splitArrayElement[0]
    let lastValue = splitArrayElement[1]
    firstValArr.append(firstValue)
    lastValArr.append(lastValue)
}
print("First Value Array : \(firstValArr)")
print("Last Value Array: \(lastValArr)")
```

Comment: it is Swift convention to name your instances starting with a lowercase letter. BTW using Array (which is a Swift native type) as a name for it is very misleading